# How can I set string as primary key and not the default id in laravel-9 & php artisan migrate doesn't read the correspondence model class when migrate

Tags: php, laravel-9

This is my migration table schema

```
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('ip_users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id('user_id',10);
            $table->string('user_uuid_id',60);
            $table->string('user_name',30);
            $table->string('user_email',30);
            $table->string('user_password',100);
            $table->boolean('user_active');
            $table->timestamp('user_date_created')->useCurrent();
            $table->timestamp('user_date_modified')->useCurrent();
            $table->comment("Registered user's credentials");
        });
    }
```

Below is my correspondence model for the migration table

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class IPUsers extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    /* Our own defined primay key */
    protected $table = 'ip_users';
    public $incrementing = false;
    protected $primaryKey = 'user_PK_id'; 

    /* To tell the eloquent model that our PrimaryKey type is not an integer*/
    protected $keyType = 'string';
}
```

When I do `php artisan migrate` the schema is stored like 'user_id' as the primary key but I want 'user_uuid_id' to be the primary key. Why doesn't the migration read the 'IPUsers' model before migration or the migration doesn't work that way?

If model has another purpose what is it?

If migration doesn't work like that, then How can I set PK to my own column rather than the default id's?

I have read in laracasts that the laravel doesn't implement the set custom owned PK. What is the solution for this?

Comment: `user_id` is an `id` field which means it's a primary key because `id` means `bigIncrements` and that in turn means `UNSIGNED BIGINT` with autoincrementing on and auto-incrementing means primary key for most DBMSs

Comment: Yep, I want user_id for count only and user_uuid_id for the primary key, so my problem is user_id automatically set to the primary key How can I avoid it?

Comment: Do not use `id` as the column type but use a type that is not a primary key type? [List of available column types](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/migrations#available-column-types) here. I imagine you need `unsignedBigInteger()`

Comment: I want the user_id to be auto increment purpose, that's what I need. I need both. id's

Comment: There is no way in Laravel to set a key as autoincrementing unless it's also the primary key. You will need to use raw DB queries but first you need to check if your DBMS supports such a use case first

Comment: What ```unsignedBigInteger()``` will do.coz When I changed like ```unsignedBigInteger()->autoincreament();``` it converts as the primary key and raise multiple primarykey error. can you explain it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247834/discussion-between-che-and-apokryfos).

Answer (score 1):

Simply add primary() to uuid field.

```
$table->string('user_uuid_id',60)->primary();
```

Comment: I know this set to primary key to user_uuid_id but before this user_id automatically set to primary key and error raise like "
  SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1068 Multiple primary key defined (SQL: alter table `ip_users` add primary key `ip_users_user_uuid_primary`(`user_uuid`))" How to set the user_id to non primary key?

Comment: @che if you only need user_id for incremental purposes, change the field for an `AUTO_INCREMENT` one and use the code suggested above.
`$table->bigIncrements('id');`

Comment: If I do ```$table->bigIncrements('user_id')``` the user_id field becomes another primary key and a collision occurs between **user_id** and **user_uuid**.